# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError without a static initializer

Tags: java

I get a java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError but I don´t have a static initializer.

Code:

```java
public static final File STANDARD_INDEX_FILE = new File(HTMLFileLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResource("index.html").getPath()); // Line 16
```

The `HTMLFileLoader` class is empty.

Exception:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.guardian.Guardian.main(Guardian.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.guardian.socket.MainSocket.<init>(MainSocket.java:16)
    at net.guardian.socket.MainSocket.<clinit>(MainSocket.java:24)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: it means you have an exception in line `new File(HTMLFileLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResource("index.html").getPath())`. Check if it works.

Comment: It´s a ``NullPointerException``. The resource is ``null``. But I don´t know why it´s in the same package as ``HTMLFileLoader``.

Comment: 1. You're calling getResource() on ClassLoader. So why would it look in the package of  HTMLFileLoader? The ClassLoader loads many classes from many different packages. Use `HTMLFileLoader.class.getResource()` if you want to look in the same package as HTMLFileLoader. 2. A resource is not a file. A resource is **NOT** a file. Once your app is released, it lives inside a jar file, not on the file system.

Comment: Works with ``getResource()``, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
public static final File STANDARD_INDEX_FILE = new File(HTMLFileLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResource("index.html").getPath()); // Line 16
```

is exactly the same as this:

```
public static final File STANDARD_INDEX_FILE;

static {
  STANDARD_INDEX_FILE = new File(HTMLFileLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResource("index.html").getPath()); // Line 16 
}
```

As in, this is what it looks like in the compiled code.

As such, you do have a static initializer; and the exception is occuring somewhere in that initializer block.